# TextFormField validator is not getting a value passed to it?

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I have a card game scoring application I am developing and I have one bug I can't seem to get figured out.  Hoping someone here sees my error and or can point to potential fixes.  I have an input like this where you can enter the score for each player for the round. It's nothing more than a column of rows with a Text() holding the players name and a TextFormField() to enter/edit the score.

[Image showing the score input/edit dialog in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JOsb.png)

Here is the code for the row:

```
              child: TextFormField(
                key: Key(p.name),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                initialValue: p.getRoundScore(round)?.toString() ?? '',
                inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3)],
                validator: (value) {
                  print('validate => ${p.name} : $value');
                  int score = int.tryParse(value);
                  return (score == null && value != null) ? "Must be a number" : null;
                },
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print('onChange => ${p.name} : $value');
                  setState(() {
                    int score = int.parse(value);
                    if (round == 9) score *= 2; // Queens round
                    if (round == 10) score *= 3; // Kings round
                    p.updateScore(round, score);
                  });
                },
              ),
```

If I enter scores, like John =2, Hannah=1, Tias=2 and Eric=0 and then click the save button, I get the following output from my print()s:

```
I/flutter (32660): onChange => John : 2
I/flutter (32660): onChange => Hannah : 1
I/flutter (32660): onChange => Tias : 2
I/flutter (32660): onChange => Eric : 0
I/flutter (32660): validate => John :
I/flutter (32660): validate => Hannah :
I/flutter (32660): validate => Tias :
I/flutter (32660): validate => Eric :
```

And the validation output in the app shows errors for each field:

[Image showing the same score entry dialog with the validation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4l8G.png)

**[EDIT]** Adding the code for the save button here for completeness:

```
   if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      debugPrint(playerToJson(players));
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }                                  }
```

What am I missing here? I could try and remove the onChange and move to using a TextController but this would add complexity as you can have 3-6 players and I'd have to have multiple controllers for it to work...they also seemed like overkill for what I needed to do.

I'm not sure why the "value" passed to the validator() is always an empty string, is there something I am doing wrong? Is this a bug?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: can you change the `null` statement to String if the String shown in the console that mean you update the widget two time on row

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  The onChange will fire over and over for each keypress and that works fine.  The validator only fires when you click the save button.  That "should" be getting whatever the text value is for that field at that time, no?  All I ever get is "" passed in to the validator though.

Comment: the first answer is right, i recommend you to return value from the button after validation not inside `TextFormField`

Comment: So validate it in the save button and NOT use the validation capability that the framework is providing?

Comment: No difference, still get "" passed as the value to validator for each field.

Comment: i think you have been misled how to use `TextFormField`, for making a text form like that you need to use three classes 1- `TextEditingController`, 2- `Form`, 3-`TextFormField `, it will make you write less code and have less error "your code is good for making small form field"

Comment: So, John, I owe you an apology. Validate is before save. I am responding on my phone based on my memory. Have just checked my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after a bunch more digging it appears that somehow having the onChange was causing my problem.  Even though all the examples from Google and others show this as perfectly acceptable, when I comment out the onChange then the validator gets the proper value passed to it for each field. This actually works out fine because I really should do the work of saving out the value to my model only after I have validated the value, so I just moved that logic into the validator.  Now all works like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wrap all your TextFormFields with a Form-Widget using also a global key for managing the form. Please also see the step 1 in [flutter validation tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation)

Comment: I already do that:


 Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(

Comment: @john Me again, not sure it relates to your issue but why do you have a key for the textformfield? In my code there is only one key at the form level.